# execute and return value from observable on retry predicate

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-kotlin

perform a task with an observable and emit value

```
private val performTask = io.reactivex.Observable.create<Boolean>({ emitter ->
// do somethinf
    emitter.onNext(true)
    emitter.onComplete()
})
```

// this is also another observable with retry. I want to retry 2 times, but only if perform task is successful.

```
fun <T> io.reactivex.Observable<T>.retryAuth(): Observable<T> {
    return this.retry ({ count, error -> 
        if (count == 2 && error is ApolloException) {
            // do something with performTask and return the value

        } else false
    })
```

just need illustration on achieving this

Comment: For normally completing flows, use `repeat(2)` for numbered or `repeat(BooleanSupplier)` for conditional retries.

Comment: repeat executes onComplete. but this execution is based on error. @akarnokd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `retryWhen`:

```
this.retryWhen({ errors ->
   val counter = AtomicInteger()
   .flatMap({ error ->
       if (counter.incrementAndGet() <= 2 && error is ApolloException) {
           return performTask
              .flatMap({ result ->
                   if (result) {
                       return Observable.just(true)
                   }
                   return Observable.error(error)
              })
       }
       return Observable.error(error)
   })  
})
```

Comment: I didn't know one could do the counter thing. Any recommeded resource to help brush up my level of competence on rx ?

Comment: Read any of the RxJava books.